# How to get product count in minicart but not their quantity

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

app\design\frontend\test\product\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\minicart.phtml

```
  <a class="action desktop showcart" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('My Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="counter qty empty"
          data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
        <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <span class="counter-label">
        <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
            <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Can anyone brief me??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> MyCart -> Display Cart Summary

There you can change the setting.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code,

`$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getItemsCount();`